# replace block of text inside txt file using powershell

Tags: powershell, newline

I have the following powershell script which replaces multiple lines of text inside any text file and it works well, but I have a minor beef with it. Whenever it replaces the lines I want it adds a blank line at the end of the txt file.

The code:

```
$oldCode =  @"
      <uservalue1 value="0" />
      <uservalue1 value="1" />
"@

$newCode = @"
      <uservalue1 value="1" />
      <uservalue1 value="2" />
"@

ls myfile.txt | foreach { 
    $fileContent = Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw
    $newFileContent = $fileContent -replace $oldCode, $newCode
    Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -Value $newFileContent
}
```

This only changes two values but it will also add an extra line break and therefore when this script runs multiple times a day then we end up with a large file containing blank lines at the end.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-NoNewline` parameter

```
Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $_.FullName -Value $newFileContent
```

Comment: Is there a way to run the above script in Powershell v2? Or how should it be modified so that it works starting from Powershell v2? The above only works in Powershell v3 or higher.